# Search: input + dropdown with Polymer

Tags: polymer, dart-polymer

I am searching a solution with input + dropdown with Dart/Polymer (material design), similar to input + list + datalist + option (autocomplete HTML5) but that I have plus:

1. Index/key related to selected element.
2. I can search the term into all content, doesn’t just in the start.

There is an interesting implementation in https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/autocomplete_ui  (http://hpoul.github.com/dart-autocomplete-ui/examples/example.html), but doesn't use Polymer elements (material design).

Someone know any another solution?

Thanks in advance.